# How to populate many2many field based on ids search(wizard)

Tags: python, xml, many-to-many, odoo, wizard

I need a many2many(product_product_ids) filled based on search result. For example, I have a search button defined on wizard view(search_test):

```
<group>
    <field name="quantity"/>
    <field name="product_product_ids"/>
</group>
 <footer>
    <button name="search_test" type="object" string="Search" class="oe_highlight"/>
       or
    <button string="Cancell" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
 </footer>
```

In wizard model, I have defined these fields and functions:

```
class sale_order_add_balerce(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'sale.order.add_balerce'
    _description = 'Sale order add balerce'

    _columns = {
    'product_product_ids': fields.many2many('product.product', string='Products'),
    'quantity' : fields.float('Quantity', default='1.0')                
}
    def search_test(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        product_obj=self.pool.get('product.product')
        #search process
        product_ids_list =  product_obj.search(cr, uid, [], context=context)
        print product_ids_list
        #populating many2many field
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'product_product_ids': (6, 0, [product_ids_list])})
        return {
            'res_model': 'product.product',
            'type':'ir.ui.view',
            'context': context, 
            'res_id': ids[0] #open wizard again
        }
```

In line

```
self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'product_product_ids': (6, 0, [product_ids_list])})
```

I attempt to update many2many field after search process, but nothing happens and I see no errors
I have also tried with these variants:

```
self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'product_product_ids': (0, 0, [product_ids_list])})

self.create(cr, uid,{'product_product_ids': (6, 0, [product_ids_list])})

self.create(cr, uid, ids, {'product_product_ids': (0, 0, [product_ids_list])})
```

However, I still don't get my many2many field filled(I don't see any changes in view).

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Many2many**

For a many2many field, a list of tuples is expected. Here is the list of tuple that are accepted, with the corresponding semantics.

**(0, 0, { values })** link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary

**(1, ID, { values })** update the linked record with id = ID (write values on it)

**(2, ID)** remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)

**(3, ID)** cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)

**(4, ID)** link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)

**(5)** unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)

**(6, 0, [IDs])** replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)

See more about [Many2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#fields)

**default_get** :

Returns default values for the fields in fields_list.
**default_get** method is called when your wizard/form is load, you need to override this method to do this.

Syntax:

```
default_get(self, cr, uid, fields_list, context=None):
```

Parameters:

**fields_list (list)** : list of fields to get the default values for (example ['field1', 'field2',])

Returns:

dictionary of the default values (set on the object model class, through user preferences, or in the context)

**Solution:**

And finally your solution is overriding default_get method to set default value for many2many field.

```
def default_get(self,cr,uid,fields,context=None):
        res = super(sale_order_add_balerce, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
        product_obj=self.pool.get('product.product')
        product_ids_list =  product_obj.search(cr, uid, [], context=context)
        res["product_product_ids"] = [(6,0,[product_ids_list])]
        return res
```

Answer (score 3):

for your method search_test(), change the return to

```
return  {
            'name': 'Name for your window',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'sale.order.add_balerce',
            'target': 'new',
            'res_id': ids[0],
            'context': context,
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

- One2many and Many2many use a special "commands" format to manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the field.

This format is a list of triplets executed sequentially, where each triplet is a command to execute on the set of records. Not all commands apply in all situations. Possible commands are:

***(0, _, values)***

adds a new record created from the provided value dict.

***(1, id, values)***

updates an existing record of id id with the values in values. Can not be used in create().

***(2, id, _)***

removes the record of id id from the set, then deletes it (from the database). Can not be used in create().

***(3, id, _)***

removes the record of id id from the set, but does not delete it. Can not be used on One2many. Can not be used in create().

***(4, id, _)***

adds an existing record of id id to the set. Can not be used on One2many.

***(5, _, _)***

removes all records from the set, equivalent to using the command 3 on every record explicitly. Can not be used on One2many. Can not be used in create().

***(6, _, ids)***

replaces all existing records in the set by the ids list, equivalent to using the command 5 followed by a command 4 for each id in ids. Can not be used on One2many.

> Note
>
> Values marked as _ in the list above are ignored and can be anything,
>   generally 0 or False.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'product_product_ids': (6, 0, [product_ids_list])})
```

to

```
self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'product_product_ids': [(6, 0, [product_ids_list])]})
```

Only you have syntax mistake to write ids on many2many field. It will take list of tuple as argument. General syntax is

```
'many2many_fieldname': [(6, 0, [list_of_ids])]
```